# VBA Deleting rows by found cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and i want to delete all rows by cell value which contain "BSB*" (so there are values like BSB 1, 2 etc) this code works partially. It deletes only every second cell which contain BSB. So i have BSB 2, 4 etc. I want to delete all rows where value BSB is present in speecific column ofc. 
p.s english is my second language so please let mi know if i need to clarify something

```
    Option Explicit
Sub PrList()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Range


Set wb = Workbooks.Open("?????")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("owssvr")

With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Find(What:="Product_Number", LookAt:=xlWhole).Name = "Product_Number"
    .Find(What:="Product_Status", LookAt:=xlWhole).Name = "Product_Status"
    .Find(What:="Group_of_product", LookAt:=xlWhole).Name = "Group_of_product"
End With

Set i = ws.Range("Product_Number", Range("Product_Number").End(xlDown))

For Each r In i
    If r Like "BSB*" Then
        r.Rows.Delete
    End If
Next r


End Sub
```

Comment: Try running the `For` loop **backwards**

Comment: @Gary's Student  you mean `End(xlup))` instead of `xl down` ?

Comment: NO .........start at the bottom of the column and work upwards.................see brainiac's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub NAPP_PrList()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Range
    Dim j as Long

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("?????")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("owssvr")

    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Find(What:="Product_Number", LookAt:=xlWhole).Name = "Product_Number"
        .Find(What:="Product_Status", LookAt:=xlWhole).Name = "Product_Status"
        .Find(What:="Group_of_product", LookAt:=xlWhole).Name = "Group_of_product"
    End With

    Set i = ws.Range("Product_Number", Range("Product_Number").End(xlDown))

    For j = i.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If i(j, 1) Like "BSB*" Then i(j, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```